# Python unzip multiple .gz files

Tags: python, gzip, 7zip

I have compressed a file into several chunks using 7zip:

HAVE:

```
foo.txt.gz.001
foo.txt.gz.002
foo.txt.gz.003
foo.txt.gz.004
foo.txt.gz.005
```

WANT:

```
foo.txt
```

How do I unzip and combine these chunks to get a single file using python?

Comment: It is not very clear from the title and the content whether you intend to package all the compressed files into one .gz file or unzip, read and concatenate contents.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Did you try anything, so far?

Comment: You should concatenate all into one file and decompress it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the list of all files.

```
files = ['/path/to/foo.txt.gz.001', '/path/to/foo.txt.gz.002', '/path/to/foo.txt.gz.003']
```

Then iterate over each file and append to a result file.

```
with open('./result.gz', 'ab') as result:  # append in binary mode
    for f in files:
        with open(f, 'rb') as tmpf:        # open in binary mode also
            result.write(tmpf.read())
```

Then extract is using [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) lib. You could use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) to avoid handle with temporary zip file.

Answer (score 0):

First you must extract all the zip files sequentially:

```
import zipfile

paths = ["path_to_1", "path_to_2" ]
extract_paths = ["path_to_extract1", "path_to_extrac2"]

for i in range(0, paths):
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(paths[i], 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall(extract_paths[i])
    zip_ref.close()
```

Next you can go to the extracted location and `read()` individual files with `open` into a `string`. Concatenate those strings and save to `foo.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, gzip, shutil
dir_name = '/Users/username/Desktop/data'
def gz_extract(directory):
    extension = ".gz"
    os.chdir(directory)
    for item in os.listdir(directory): # loop through items in dir
      if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".gz" extension
          gz_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
          file_name = (os.path.basename(gz_name)).rsplit('.',1)[0] #get file name for file within
          with gzip.open(gz_name,"rb") as f_in, open(file_name,"wb") as f_out:
              shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
          os.remove(gz_name) # delete zipped file      
gz_extract(dir_name)
```

Comment: useful link: https://medium.com/@sbisen/unzip-multiple-files-with-python-d3823ccfea25

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32939094)